# Python Flask + Matplotlib not updating

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, matplotlib, flask

I'm trying to write a dynamic website using python's Flask library so that I can dynamically update graphs that are being generated by a python script (which uses Matplotlib. I have built a basic web page around this, with the most relevant part being this form and its accompanying javascript function:

Form:

```
<span>
    <form onsubmit="handleSubmit(event)">
        <input type="text" class="textbox" id="n" style="width: 100px; height: 30px">
        <input type="text" class="textbox" id="v" style="width: 100px; height: 30px">
        <input type="text" class="textbox" id="m" style="width: 100px; height: 30px">
        <button type="submit" style="height: 30px">Calculate</button>
    </form>
</span>  
<br><br>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Js function (handleSubmit(event)):

```
function handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{  url_for('index')  }}",
        data: { n : $('#n').val(),
                v: $('#v').val(),
                m: $('#v').val()
              },
    }).then(data => {
    $('#results').html(data);
    });
}
```

And here's the python Flask code for your convenience, just in case you need it:

```
from hydrogen import getProbability, saveProbabilityDistribution
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    print("Started!\n")
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.post('/')
def generate():
    data = request.form
    n = int(data.get('n'))
    v = int(data.get('v'))
    m = int(data.get('m'))

    print(f"n: {n}, v: {v}, m: {m}")

    toGraph = getProbability(n, v, m)
    saveProbabilityDistribution(toGraph)

    print("computation completed")

    return render_template('results.html', **locals())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(
        host = '127.0.0.1',
        port = 5001,
        debug = True
    )
```

And if you might need to know what the "saveProbabilityDistribution(toGraph)" function looks like, because that's the function that's part of the problem (this code is from hydrogen.py):

```
def saveProbabilityDistribution(data):
    #NOTE: depends on data returned by getProbability function

    plt.plot(data[0], data[1])
    for key in data[2]:
        plt.scatter(key, data[2][key])
    plt.savefig('static/assets/graph.png')
```

The main problem right now is that when I press the "Calculate" button the first time the website loads, I get exactly the functionality I want: graph data gets calculated, a graph image gets generated and saved as graph.png, and it gets displayed onto my html page. All's good. **BUT** when I try to click the "Calculate" button again (to resubmit the form with new values), the data gets calculated and a graph image gets generated and stored, BUT NO GRAPH IMAGE IS DISPLAYED TO THE HTML PAGE. I have tried everything, and I don't know what to do anymore.

Just some more info just in case someone might need it:
Here's everything that's in results.html:

```
<div style="max-width: 75%;">
    <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='assets/graph.png') }}"/>
</div>
```

**NOTE: THE GRAPHS ARE GENERATED USING MATPLOTLIB**